# OnClickListener for headers of RecyclerView is not getting invoked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to sort my recyclerview on click of a column header (e.g if Name and age are two columns of the recyclerview, I want to sort the list when I click on header Age). I have added the headers by including the headers layout in my activity layout that contains recyclerview.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <include layout="@layout/header_item"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/intrinsic_padding"
            android:paddingTop="50dp"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my activity class with above layout, I set the adapter for recyclerview and add onClickListener for Textview Age.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView ageTextview;

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<User> usersList=initUsers();

    // Create RecyclerView List
    mRecyclerView=findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mAdapter=new RecyclerAdapter(usersList, getApplicationContext());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    ageTextview=findViewById(R.id.ageHeader);

    ageTextview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Column -- Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Collections.sort(usersList, new Comparator<User>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(User user1, User user2) {
                        if (user1.getAge() < user2.getAge())
                        return -1;
                        else if (user1.getAge()==user2.getAge())
                            return 0;
                        else
                            return 1;
                    }
                });
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
}
}

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<User> users;

private Context context;

RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<User> users, Context context)
{
    this.users=users;
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false);
    return new VHItem(view);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof VHItem) {
        User user = users.get(position);

        ((VHItem)holder).userName.setText(user.getUserName());
        ((VHItem)holder).age.setText(String.valueOf(user.getAge()));
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (users !=null)
    {
        System.out.println("Number of users: "+ users.size());
        return users.size();
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

public static class VHItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public View view;
    TextView userName;
    TextView age;

    VHItem(View view)
    {
        super(view);
        this.view=view;
        this.userName=view.findViewById(R.id.username);
        this.age=view.findViewById(R.id.age);
    }
}
```

}

When I click on Age header, there is no effect. Neither sorting happens nor Toast is displayed. Looks like onClick() method is not getting invoked at all. The log does not show any errors.
In the layout file header_item, I have tried adding android:clickable="true", android:focusable="false". But nothing works.

Please help me understand if I am doing anything wrong. Is adding headers using a separate layout file the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Try changing ageTextview from wrap content to some fixed height and width...

Comment: Please also paste code, how you are initializing the adapter, your adapter class, and the layout you are inflating.

Comment: I have edited my question with adapter code. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

Try to get  `OnClickListner` from `ViewHolder`. Like this,

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView ageTextview;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        ageTextview = temView.findViewById(R.id.ageTextview) ;

        ageTextview.setOnClickListener(..);

    }
}
```